# http add sslcert fails when done programmatically

Tags: c#, ssl

I have developed a self-hosted api.

The api traffic needs to run over SSL.

Using a combination of netsh commands I have managed to successfully add the certificate and then bind a route to my service. Happy Days.

But, I have to write an installer to do this programmatically.

The problem is that when I add the certificate using my c# code, I can see it the certificate MMC but when I try to bind to it I get an error of:

```
SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312
A specified log-on session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```

As I say, when I do it manually with these steps I don't get the problem...

1. List item
2. Double click on the .pfx file.
3. MMC opens.
4. I select "Local Machine"
5. On the next screen I confirm the .pfx file location and name.
6. I enter the password for the certificate and select "Include all extended properties"
7. On the next screen I let it default to  "Automatically select the certificate store based on the type of certificate"
8. I then get a confirmation screen.
9. When I click "Finish" I get a message "The import was successful"

I can then see it in MMC under Personal > Certificates

And it lets me add the route using netsh from a command prompt  - Happy Days.

When I try an do it programmatically with the following code:

```
public static bool ConfigureSSLCertificate(string file, string password, string method)
    {
        try
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(file, password);

            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            if (!store.Certificates.Contains(cert))
            {
                if (method == "add")
                {
                    store.Add(cert);
                }
            }
            if (method == "remove")
            {
                store.Remove(cert);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }
```

The certificate appears in my MMC in exactly the same place but when I try and add the route with the exact same netsh command as before I get the error mentioned above:

```
netsh>http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8088 certhash=fb93ce2c4d8bd88c82e63e3372a050ba84f15e94 appid={bb14356a-a14f-4589-82ce-b80d38b8741e}
```

For some reason, when I add the certificate manually using the MMC and when I run my code something is different. Something that is stopping the route being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually simple - I too have struggled with this, and have now found the solution. How can a manually added certificate differ from the programatically added one? Well, the short answer is to change your certificate load line to this:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(file, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

The key being that last parameter, which tells the certificate to save the private key stored in the machine location, and not the user location. Then the `netsh` command can find the private key, and can work.

The solution was found in the explanatory text by [Paul Stovell](http://paulstovell.com/blog/x509certificate2) and some digging to see how I could set that flag when loading the certificate into the store.

Now, why I can't programmatically do the netsh function is another matter...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have fixed it.

there was a problem with the .pfx I had been trying to install. I have no idea why. what fixed it for me was exporting a working certificate from my personal store with all options set to true and then run it in the following:

```
public static bool ServiceInstall(string serviceName, string serviceDescription, string executablePath)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceProcessInstaller ProcesServiceInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            ProcesServiceInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

            ServiceInstaller ServiceInstallerObj = new ServiceInstaller();
            InstallContext Context = new System.Configuration.Install.InstallContext();
            String path = String.Format("/assemblypath={0}", executablePath);
            String[] cmdline = { path };

            Context = new System.Configuration.Install.InstallContext("", cmdline);
            ServiceInstallerObj.Context = Context;
            ServiceInstallerObj.DisplayName = serviceName;
            ServiceInstallerObj.Description = serviceDescription;
            ServiceInstallerObj.ServiceName = serviceName;
            ServiceInstallerObj.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
            ServiceInstallerObj.Parent = ProcesServiceInstaller;

            System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary state = new System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary();
            ServiceInstallerObj.Install(state);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

and then use that pfx file

I have no idea why the old pfx worked from the command line but didn't work from code.

HTH

Comment: All I did is that I just exported the certificate as .pfx with private key, and than using the same code (but with newly created cert) all worked fine.